# Is there a way to list all the files that contain XXX in their file name?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

Example search: I want to show **all** the files with `.connect` in their name. In order to do this in VSCode, I hit ⌘ + p and type `connect` in the command pallet that lets me navigate to any file or symbol by typing its name. Like this:

[image: Command Pallet]

I was wondering if there was a way to do this in a persistent window, like how search works. I'm not looking for anything *within* the file, so I can't use the normal search. Rather, I'm looking to filter the files based on a search term and the filename. The reason the command pallet doesn't work for me is that everytime I click on a file, it goes away, and I have to retype `.connect` and scroll down every single time.

My less-than-ideal solution is to find a common thing in all these .connect files and use that as a search term, and I have essentially performed the same search.

[image]

Comment: You can filter the Explorer file list - did you consider that?

Comment: you have to enable this `Explorer Search`